# ExpressibleByStringLiteral

Tags: swift, enumeration, string-literals

Why does (let key1:Keyword = "if") go well but (let key2:Keyword = String("if")) go wrong?

```
public enum Keyword: String, ExpressibleByStringLiteral, ExpressibleByUnicodeScalarLiteral, ExpressibleByExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteral {    
case `if` = "if"
case `else` = "else"
public init(stringLiteral:String){
    self.init(rawValue: stringLiteral)!
}
public init(unicodeScalarLiteral value: String) {
    self.init(rawValue: value)!
}
public init(extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral value: String) {
    self.init(rawValue: value)!
}
}

let key1:Keyword = "if" //going well
let key2:Keyword = String("if") //error reported
```

Comment: Because `"if"` is a string **literal,** and `String("if")` is not (it is an expression of type "String")

Comment: Unrelated, but this isn't really a good use of `ExpressibleByStringLiteral`, as you'll get a crash at runtime for invalid keywords. If you just access the enum cases normally, you'll get compile-time enforcement.

Comment: @Hamish Yes, you’re quite right. It’s not suitable to use literal here. Thanks!

Comment: @MartinR Thank you very much. I c it